# Не работает функция добавления таска в TODO

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, делаю TODOшку, и никак не получается функция добавления нового таска а помощью кнопки ADD. Для начала хочу добавить только поле ввода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом добавлю другие элементы.

```js
function myData(dateId, timeId) //Выводит дату по клику, РАБОТАЕТ
{
  temp_date = new Date();
  day = temp_date.getDate();
  month = temp_date.getMonth() + 1;
  year = temp_date.getFullYear();
  hours = temp_date.getHours();
  minutes = temp_date.getMinutes();

  if (day < 10) {
    day = "0" + day;
  }

  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  document.getElementById(dateId).innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
  document.getElementById(timeId).innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes;


  // Добавление тасков

  const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
  //addButton.className = "button";
  const inputTask = document.getElementById('inp');
  inputTask.className = "input_task";
  const unfinishedTasks = document.getElementById('unfinished_tasks');
  unfinishedTasks.className = "todos";
  const finishedTasks = document.getElementById('finished_tasks');

  function createNewElement(task) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    let checkbox = document.createElement('span'); //Создаем элемент
    checkbox.className = "block_input"; //Задаем класс элементу
    checkbox.innerHTML = task;
    //checkbox.innerHTML = "<i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
    //Вставляем элемент внутрь - checkbox

    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);

    return listItem;
  }

  function addTask() {
    if (inputTask.value) {
      let listItem = createNewElement(inputTask.value);
      unfinishedTasks.appendChild(listItem);
      inputTask.value = "";
    }

    addButton.onclick = addTask;

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #373737;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 5% 0 2% 38%;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.input_task {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  width: 625px;
  height: 24px;
}

.input_add {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 123px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#add {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 110px;
  height: 20;
  background: #0097f4;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.sort {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.number {
  margin: 5px 20px 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 25px;
  align-items: center;
}

.search {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 514px;
  height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a6a6a6;
}

.number p {
  color: #ada6a7;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fa-sort {
  color: #ada6a7;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.fa-sort-asc {
  color: #ada6a7;
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

.fa-sort-desc {
  color: #ada6a7;
  margin-top: -21px;
}

.fa-search {
  color: #ada6a7;
  margin-top: 14px;
  left: -39%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.fa-filter {
  color: #ada6a7;
  margin: 14px 0 0 47px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 18px 0 10px;
}

.data__number {
  font-size: 135%;
}

.data__time {}

.block_number {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  margin: 7px 0;
  background: #717171;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 26px;
}

.block_angle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 7px 10px 0 20px;
}

.block_input {
  color: black;
  width: 516px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.todos {
  height: 55px;
  width: 516px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 18px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  /*display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;*/
}

.block_input2 {
  background: #d1eef4;
  color: black;
  width: 516px;
}

.block_input3 {
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  width: 516px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #0097f4;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #0097f4;
}

.fa-pencil {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3f8c3f;
  padding: 11px;
  color: white;
  margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
  height: 38px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.fa-check {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0097f4;
  padding: 11px;
  color: white;
  margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
  height: 38px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.fa-trash {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0097f4;
  padding: 11px;
  color: white;
  margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
  height: 38px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.small a {
  padding: 7px 28px;
  font-size: 90%;
}

a.not_active {
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #0097f4;
}

.delete {
  width: 14%;
  height: 99px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 11%;
  top: 29%;
}

.edit {
  width: 21%;
  height: 220px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 29%;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  font-size: 120%;
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.edit__box {
  background: #fffafa;
  height: 60%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: -10px 0 13px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  border-right: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  width: 3px;
  height: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 43%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0a8ce8c2c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
  <div class="input_add">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Task" class="input_task" id="inp">

    <div class="button">
      <button onclick="addTask()" id="add">ADD</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort">
    <i class="fa fa-sort fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="number">
      <i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>123</p>
      <i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input name="name" value="" class="input_task search">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="data">
      <p class="data__number" id="current_date_time_block">12.10.2018</p>
      <!-- onload="myData()" -->
      <p class="data__time" id="current_time_block">13:24</p>
    </div>
    <p class="block_number">1</p>
    <div class="block_angle">
      <li class="task_wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </li>
    </div>
    <ul class="todos" id="unfinished_tasks">
      <li>
        <span onclick="myData('current_date_time_block', 'current_time_block')" class="block_input" id="span_value">Вымыть кухню
                </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="delete delete_active">
        <h2>Delete Item?</h2>
        <div class="button small">
            <a class="not_active">NO</a>
            <a>YES</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="edit edit_active">
        <h3>Edit text</h3>
        <div class="edit__box">
            <p>New text of todo item...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button small">
            <a class="not_active">CANSEL</a>
            <a>SAVE</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="line">
    </div>-->

</div>
```

Код размещен в песочнице с возможностью редактирования  https://jsfiddle.net/mdtg5pw8/2/

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Для начала исправьте ошибки синтаксиса, как минимум у вас неправильно закрыт блок кода функции `myData`. Дальше идите за ошибками в консоли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **UPD** - возможно, скрипт в шапке документа `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` и есть оригинал, если это так, то там он работать не будет.
2. Пропущена одна скобка `{`
3. Второй раз кто-то решил присабачить обработчик прям внутри функции `addButton.onclick = addTask`

Короче обычные мелкие пакости от невнимательности.
Держи: https://jsfiddle.net/qsvwy91n/

Comment: не понял первый пункт

Comment: @Grundy в оригинале, см. выше `<button onclick="addTask()" id="add">ADD</button>`

Comment: и что не так с этой записью?

Comment: а какая связь где подключается скрипт и Html с инлайновым обработчиком?

Comment: для инлайно нужно только чтобы функция глобальная была, где объявлена функция - не важно

Comment: @Grundy да действительно работает, вот те на. Точно, это у него обработчика не было, и ошибка соответственно выскакивала - `click()` не определена. Но код бы все равно не работал, там кроме обработчика и другие `id`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Grundy прав ))) А за ответ с примером плюсик )